# Codeigniter: Custom config or constant?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some global settings variables I need to store for my application, but I'm confused as to whether I should use a custom config file or just add new constants to the bottom of the config/constants.php file? These variables won't be changing once set, so are constants the right choice?

What's the difference between the two, and how does Codeigniter handle them?

Comment: I would say: always go with custom...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Custom config file IMO. That will make your life easier down the line when you decide to upgrade to a new major release of CI, since you'll be able to overwrite `config.php` without losing critical application constants.

The application-wide `config.php` is always loaded, so anything you put in there will be globally available, whereas [custom config files](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html) can be loaded on-demand, saving resources and providing better separation of code responsibilities.

**Example: On-demand loading of a config file:**

```
$this->config->load('filename');
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense--I neglected to think ahead to dealing with CI updates!

Comment: The links seems broken. Can you fix it?

Comment: Link to doc is fixed.